# Sql Server Subquery Looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a subquery that sums the days a Listing has been active. There are 3 different priorities for these listings that we want to analyze seperately. The subqueries works fine but I have to repeat myself 3 times and i can't help feeling like someone could point me in a more elegant direction.

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
Declare @Priorities text = ['H','M','L']

Foreach(priority in priorities)
  (SELECT SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END)
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND jlh_inner.Priority = priority)
```

Full code right now is:

```
BEGIN
SELECT rof.location AS location,
    jlh.TitleId AS TitleId,
    jt.Title AS Title,
    (SELECT SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END)
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND jlh_inner.Priority = 'H') AS HighPriorityDays,
    (SELECT SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END)
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND jlh_inner.Priority = 'M') AS MediumPriorityDays,
    (SELECT SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END)
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND jlh_inner.Priority = 'L') AS LowPriorityDays

FROM Offices rof,
    ListingHistory jlh,
    JobTitle jt

WHERE rof.code = jlh.OfficeCode
AND jt.JobTitleID = jlh.JobTitleId

GROUP BY rof.location, rof.code, jlh.TitleId, jt.Title

ORDER BY location
```

END

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some very bad coding practices that you need to stop using entirely and correlated subqueries are one of them. They are performance killers and there is no reason to ever use one. Also you should start using explicit joins especially since you are using SQL Server and the inmplicit join syntax for outer joins not only is deprecated but is actually broken even back to SQL server 2000 and combining implicit inner and explicit out joins often leads to incorrect results and thus implicit joins are harder to maintain, and are much more likely to have accidental cross joins and are, of course, almost 20 years out of date.

See if this code does what you need:

```
SELECT rof.location AS location,     
jlh.TitleId AS TitleId,     
jt.Title AS Title,     
SUM(CASE WHEN(jlh.StartDate IS NULL and Priority <> 'H') THEN 0  
    WHEN(jlh.EndDate IS NULL AND Priority = 'H') 
    THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, GETDATE())             
    WHEN (jlh.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND Priority = 'H') THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, jlh.EndDate) END) AS HighPriorityDays,     
SUM(CASE WHEN(jlh.StartDate IS NULL and Priority <> 'M') THEN 0  
    WHEN(jlh.EndDate IS NULL AND Priority = 'M') 
    THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, GETDATE())             
    WHEN (jlh.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND Priority = 'M') THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, jlh.EndDate) END) AS MediumPriorityDays,
SUM(CASE WHEN(jlh.StartDate IS NULL and Priority <> 'L') THEN 0  
    WHEN(jlh.EndDate IS NULL AND Priority = 'L') 
    THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, GETDATE())             
    WHEN (jlh.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND Priority = 'L') THEN DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, jlh.EndDate) END) AS LowPriorityDays  
FROM Offices rof 
JOIN    ListingHistory jlh 
    ON rof.code = jlh.OfficeCode
JOIN     JobTitle jt  
    ON jt.JobTitleID = jlh.JobTitleId  
GROUP BY rof.location, rof.code, jlh.TitleId, jt.Title  
ORDER BY location
```

Comment: Thanks for this @HLGEM it works excellent and is very easy to read. SQL is not my forte and Sql Server i am completely new with. I didn't know implicit joins were so broken. I won't use them so much anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with HLGEM, using the join syntax is more appropriate. It also fits into the OUTER APPLY syntax.  This achieves what you want with consise code without revisiting the table 3 times.

```
SELECT rof.location AS location,
    jlh.TitleId AS TitleId,
    jt.Title AS Title,
    sum(case when PD.Priority='H' then PD.PriorityDays end) as HighPriorityDays,
    sum(case when PD.Priority='M' then PD.PriorityDays end) as MediumPriorityDays,
    sum(case when PD.Priority='L' then PD.PriorityDays end) as LowPriorityDays
FROM Offices rof
inner join ListingHistory jlh on rof.code = jlh.OfficeCode
inner join JobTitle jt on jt.JobTitleID = jlh.JobTitleId
outer apply
    (SELECT jlh_inner.Priority, SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END) as PriorityDays
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND jlh_inner.Priority in ('H','L','M')
    GROUP BY jlh_inner.Priority) PD
GROUP BY rof.location, rof.code, jlh.TitleId, jt.Title
ORDER BY location
```

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen outer apply before and this is a good example.

Comment: @Chris - But you still leave `cyberkiwi` with a reputation score of 1! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than declaring @priorities as an array of texts, make it a table, then insert your three values into the @priorities table and join your existing aggregation query on the newly-minted @priorities table.  This will get you one result row per row of your priorities table, which I think is what you're really after, right?

Here's how I'd do the table setup in MS SQL:

```
declare @priorities table (
priority char(1)
)

insert into @priorities (priority) values ('H')
insert into @priorities (priority) values ('M')
insert into @priorities (priority) values ('L')
```

This would make your end implementation include something like this:

```
SELECT jlh_inner.Priority, SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(jlh_inner.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
            WHEN(jlh_inner.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, GETDATE())
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(dd, jlh_inner.StartDate, jlh_inner.EndDate)
        END)
    FROM ListingHistory jlh_inner
    INNER JOIN @priorities p on jlh_inner.Priority = p.priorities
    WHERE jlh_inner.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND jlh_inner.OfficeCode = rof.code
```

Then you add the Priority field to the GROUP BY clause you've already got, and things should aggregate up nicely.

Comment: I like how you did this. Using a table of values makes more sense than how I was thinking of going about it.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it!  It's the way I personally would approach this problem, though I'd probably add an orderNumber field to my @priorities table so I can order the results very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would refactor it using a common table expression (which represents the summaries grouped appropriately) and explicit joins:

```
WITH Summaries AS (
   SELECT jlh.JobTitleId
          ,jlh.OfficeCode
          ,jlh.Priority
          ,SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN(jlh.StartDate IS NULL) THEN 0
                WHEN(jlh.EndDate IS NULL) THEN
                    DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, GETDATE())
                ELSE
                    DATEDIFF(dd, jlh.StartDate, jlh.EndDate)
            END
          ) AS DayCount
    FROM ListingHistory jlh
    GROUP BY jlh.JobTitleId
          ,jlh.OfficeCode
          ,jlh.Priority
)
SELECT rof.location AS location
    ,jlh.TitleId AS TitleId
    ,jt.Title AS Title
    ,s_h.DayCount AS HighPriorityDays
    ,s_m.DayCount AS MediumPriorityDays
    ,s_l.DayCount AS LowPriorityDays
FROM Offices rof
INNER JOIN ListingHistory jlh
    ON rof.code = jlh.OfficeCode
INNER JOIN JobTitle jt
    ON jt.JobTitleID = jlh.JobTitleId
LEFT JOIN Summaries s_h
    ON s_h.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND s_h.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND s_h.Priority = 'H'
LEFT JOIN Summaries s_m
    ON s_m.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND s_m.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND s_m.Priority = 'M'
LEFT JOIN Summaries s_l
    ON s_l.JobTitleId = jlh.JobTitleId
    AND s_l.OfficeCode = rof.code
    AND s_l.Priority = 'L'
GROUP BY rof.location, rof.code, jlh.TitleId, jt.Title
ORDER BY location
```